# R Shiny app: output flashes out after changing the position in UI

Tags: r, shiny, bslib

I am new to R Shiny and currently reading about the clicking behaviour, chapter 7 of the book *Mastering Shiny*.

I don't understand why after changing the location of `tableOutput()` in UI will cause a flash out effect on the outputs?

The shared component:

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg)
  }, res = 96)
  
  output$info <- renderPrint({
    req(input$plot_click)
    x <- round(input$plot_click$x, digits = 2)
    y <- round(input$plot_click$y, digits = 2)
    cat("[", x, ", ", y, " ]", sep = "")
  })
  
  output$data <- renderTable({
    nearPoints(mtcars, coordinfo = input$plot_click, xvar = "wt", yvar = "mpg")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This UI works, but the output is squashed. I'd like to place it below the main plot:

```
ui <- page_sidebar(
  
  sidebar = sidebar(
    title = "Global controls",
    
    varSelectInput(inputId = "x", label = "X:", data = df),
    
    varSelectInput(inputId = "y", label = "Y:", data = df)
  ),
  
  card(
    full_screen = TRUE,
    layout_sidebar(
      sidebar = sidebar(
        title = "Coordinate of where you click:",
        position = "left",
        
        verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "info"),

        ########### the position of this line #################
        tableOutput(outputId = "data")
        #######################################################
      ),
      
      plotOutput(outputId = "plot", click = "plot_click")
    )
  )
)
```

[image]

This UI doesn't work properly, as the output disappears after a quick flash. In addition, the other output `verbatimTextOutput()` also disappeared:

```
ui <- page_sidebar(
  
  sidebar = sidebar(
    title = "Global controls",
    
    varSelectInput(inputId = "x", label = "X:", data = df),
    
    varSelectInput(inputId = "y", label = "Y:", data = df)
  ),
  
  card(
    full_screen = TRUE,
    layout_sidebar(
      sidebar = sidebar(
        title = "Coordinate of where you click:",
        position = "left",
        
        verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "info")
      ),
      
      plotOutput(outputId = "plot", click = "plot_click"),

      ########### the position of this line #################
      tableOutput(outputId = "data")
      #######################################################

    )
  )
)
```

[image]

It would be much appreciated if someone can explain what caused this behaviour, and how I can correct it.